# Processing Scala Option[T]

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have a Scala `Option[T]`. If the value is `Some(x)` I want to process it with a a process that does not return a value (`Unit`), but if it is `None`, I want to print an error.

I can use the following code to do this, but I understand that the more idiomatic way is to treat the `Option[T]` as a sequence and use `map`, `foreach`, etc. How do I do this?

```
opt match {
  case Some(x) => // process x with no return value, e.g. write x to a file
  case None => // print error message
}
```

Comment: you may want take a look at [Tony Morris' scala.Option Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Link has changed into http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala's `Option` is, sadly, missing a method to do exactly this.  I add one:

```
class OptionWrapper[A](o: Option[A]) {
  def fold[Z](default: => Z)(action: A => Z) = o.map(action).getOrElse(default)
}
implicit def option_has_utility[A](o: Option[A]) = new OptionWrapper(o)
```

which has the slightly nicer (in my view) usage

```
op.fold{ println("Empty!") }{ x => doStuffWith(x) }
```

You can see from how it's defined that `map`/`getOrElse` can be used instead of pattern matching.

Alternatively, `Either` already has a `fold` method.  So you can

```
op.toRight(()).fold{ _ => println("Empty!") }{ x => doStuffWith(x) }
```

but this is a little clumsy given that you have to provide the left value (here `()`, i.e. Unit) and then define a function on that, rather than just stating what you want to happen on `None`.

The pattern match isn't bad either, especially for longer blocks of code.  For short ones, the overhead of the match starts getting in the way of the point.  For example:

```
op.fold{ printError }{ saveUserInput }
```

has a lot less syntactic overhead than

```
op match {
  case Some(x) => saveUserInput(x)
  case None => printError
}
```

and therefore, once you expect it, is a lot easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 6):

I think explicit pattern matching suits your use case best.

Comment: I chose Rex Kerr's answer because it actually answered the question that I asked, but I have to agree that for readability, pattern matching wins, especially if the code must be read by people who are less familiar with Scala. +1

Comment: @Ralph: Readability, familiarity etc etc is not what I had in mind when I suggested pattern matching. I in general prefer higher order combinators to explicit pattern matching. That IMO leads to better readability (once you know what those combinators do), concision, and of course composability. Although `.fold` or `.cata` combinator corresponds to your use case, you have two non-trivial (read pointful) blocks of code to execute for each case, and thus using combinator over pattern matching doesn't really buy you anything in terms of readability or concision. Hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to simply and safely use `opt.get` which itself throws a `NoSuchElementException` exception if `opt` is `None`. Or if you want to throw your own exception, you can do this:

```
val x = opt.getOrElse(throw new Exception("Your error message"))
// x is of type T
```

Comment: I do not want to throw an error message. I just need to print an error to std err. I suppose I can wrap the whole thing in a try-catch, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Yes, try-catch would be the best strategy. You can either wrap all your file-writing related code in the try block or better factor it out to some method. Also note the updates to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is the best choice here.

However, if you want to treat Option as a sequence and to map over it, you can do it, because Unit is a value:

```
opt map { v =>
  println(v) // process v (result type is Unit)
} getOrElse {
  println("error")
}
```

By the way, printing an error is some kind of "anti-pattern", so it's better to throw an exception anyway:

```
opt.getOrElse(throw new SomeException)
```

Comment: I am writing a very simple utility to traverse several million files listed in a text file and generate copy commands for them. I simply want to print a small error message if the file is missing or cannot be read. The copy commands go to stdout and the errors to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

as @missingfaktor says, you are in the exact scenario where pattern matching is giving the most readable results.
If Option has a value you want to do something, if not you want to do something else.

While there are various ways to use map and other functional constructs on Option types, they are generally useful when:

you want to use the Some case and ignore the None case e.g. in your case

```
opt.map(writeToFile(_)) //(...if None just do nothing)
```

or you want to chain the operations on more than one option and give a result only when all of them are Some. For instance, one way of doing this is:

```
val concatThreeOptions = 
for {
  n1 <- opt1
  n2 <- opt2
  n3 <- opt3
} yield n1 + n2 + n3 // this will be None if any of the three is None
                     // we will either write them all to a file or none of them
```

but none of these seem to be your case